# Calculate value based on number between a class using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**What I am trying to achieve**: I want to grab the price of a product on the Squarespace platform and display the discounted price for members as a text.

On Squarespace's HTML, the price is displayed as

```html
<span class="sqs-money-native">26.00</span>
```

Here is a code I built in 2 hours after learning basics from here and there:

```js
span.onkeyup = function () {
    var result = document.getElementById('premium');
    result.innerHTML = eval(this.value)*0.9;
  
  var result = document.getElementById('platinum');
    result.innerHTML = eval(this.value)*6*0.9;
  
};

//evaluate initial value
span.onkeyup();
```

And here is what I am using in the HTML code block

```html
Premium members: $<span id="premium"></span>

Platinum members: $<span id="platinum"></span>
```

but it is returning NaN as output.

Comment: you really don't need that `eval()`... you need `Number(this.textContent)`.
since `value` is a property of input fields, and a `<span>` doesn't have it

Comment: Even without `Number()` it should work as expected: `"6" * 5 == 6 * 5`.

Comment: Where did you get the idea to use `eval` ?

Comment: Also a span does not have a value. It has innerText and innerHTML or textContent

Answer (score 0):

`span` elements do not have a `value` property, and as commented the `eval` is not needed.

Instead use `textContent` and `Number`, and it's best not to repeat yourself

```
span.onkeyup = function () {
    const val = Number(this.textContent); // not strictly necessary (see below)

    var premiumResult  = document.getElementById('premium');
    premiumResult.innerHTML = val*0.9;
  
    var platinumResult= document.getElementById('platinum');
    platinumResult.innerHTML = val*6*0.9;
  
};
```

I find it useful to be explicit that I want that text value to be treated as a number, but when you try to multiply it, it will automatically convert the result to a number for you.

Comment: Not a great suggestion to reuse a variable name in the same scope

Comment: @mplungjan I didnt even spot that, was just taken from the OP. Thanks.

Comment: Also the result will be REALLY ugly.

Comment: @mplungjan - on that point. One step at a time ;) That will be their next question.

Comment: Also no need for keyUp when we have click event - and eventListeners

Comment: Who knows. Does the OP want a `keyup` or a `click`. I can only answer the question given!  My mindreading skills are lacking today. I'm not sure keyup on a span is even useful, but that is for them to decide

Answer (score 0):

Several issues

- a span does not have a value. It has innerText or textContent and innerHTML
- no need to eval, not even a need to cast to number since * will do that for you. I do it anyway, here using the unary `+` operator
- JS Math will make very ugly numbers so let's format them with toFixed(2) for the decimals
- Delegate from the nearest container and interrogate the class of the target you want
- for a non-input field, use the click event. Otherwise you can use the `input` event for an input field. keyUp is not an event I would use here
- Have a variable for each result or don't have a variable like here:

```js
document.getElementById("someId").addEventListener("click", function(e) { // or document.querySelector(".someClass")
  const tgt = e.target; // the element we clicked
  if (tgt.classList.contains("sqs-money-native")) { // is it one of the spans?
    const val = +tgt.textContent;
    document.getElementById('premium').textContent = (val * 0.9).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('platinum').textContent = (val * 6 * 0.9).toFixed(2);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="someId" class="someClass">
  <span class="sqs-money-native">26.00</span>
  <span class="sqs-money-native">27.00</span>
  <span class="sqs-money-native">28.00</span>
</div>

Premium members: $<span id="premium">0.00</span> Platinum members: $<span id="platinum">0.00</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input and feedback.

I created a code pen here https://codepen.io/gabruconcepts/pen/bGqZWEX and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: That is because getElementsByClassName is plural so you would need `document.getElementsByClassName("sqs-money-native")[0].addEventListener...`. But instead use `document.querySelector(".sqs-money-native")` if you only have one of them. If more, wrap them in a container and use my delegation